# Are there any command line calendar (ics) readers which can handle rrule (recurring events)?

Tags: command-line, calendar, google-calendar

Using [this demo calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/ssjqjrg27h9mqqctfnr5kscmrk%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics):

For graphical calendar readers, the output looks like this:

[image: screenclip 215]

But from the various npm and python projects, all I get is variations of this, where it only shows the first event of a series, and if the first event is in the past, then nothing at all:

```
On 2018-10-09, Event repeating monthly on 2nd tuesday at 10am
On 2018-10-10, Event repeating weekly on a Wednesday at 11am
On 2018-10-11, Single event on 11th October
```

Would really like to find a command line app where I can just simply parse the calendar (from file or url) and get a plain text listing. Thanks!

Please note, ical is a calendar specification, NOT related to iCal, the Apple app! I'm not asking for iCal on Ubuntu, I'm asking to read an ical (ics) spec file on Ubuntu (command line, output as text). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it to remind, then pipe it to awk or sed to butcher it

```
$ cat calendar.ics | ics2rem | remind -s -
2020/12/05 * * * * Test repeated
2020/12/06 * * * * Test repeated
2020/12/07 * * 60 840 2:00-3:00pm 2pm dec 7 2020 appointment
2020/12/07 * * * * Test repeated
```

Comment: https://github.com/greyson/ics2rem in case you don't have it.